# Which touchscreens do you prefer for flash kiosk work?

Tags: flash, touchscreen, kiosk

Our company does a lot of flash work and occasionally offline / kiosk applications.  I'd like to recommend a touchscreen to our client but don't know enough about the market.

Anyone have any good experiences with any particular model of touchscreen?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELO Touchscreens are the best, out of the few vendors I've used.

Answer (score 0):

There is several technology of touch screens in the  market,as i know and we are using in our company there  two more famous are resistance based and capacitance based,

as my experience :

resistance based are easier to work with ,less push ,and even you can **use a pen**, but less life,

capacitance based are some hard to work for persons with **large finger-prints** or hard dry fingers, but more life